# How to check whether String is not equal to multiple other Strings ignoring case

Tags: java, string, equals

I have a program that is asking a user for a day of the week. I am trying to test the answer given by the user and give them another chance to answer if they misspell a day or enter something else. My equals is either ignoring the Scanner before it or printing out the while statement no matter what day I put in.

```
System.out.println("Great! Welcome back " + cust.getName() + ". What day of the week would you like "
            + "to book?(Sunday, November the 12th thru Saturday, November the 18th");

    String day = scan.nextLine();
    String dayLower = day.toLowerCase();
    scan.nextLine();


    while (!"monday".equals(dayLower) && !dayLower.equals("tuesday") && !dayLower.equals("wednesday")
            && !dayLower.equals("thursday") && !dayLower.equals("friday") && !dayLower.equals("saturday")
            && !dayLower.equals("sunday")) {
        System.out.println("Error in entry. Please enter a day of the week.");
        day = scan.nextLine();
    }
```

Comment: Note: you have a floating `scan.nextLine();` which discard one line and you only convert to lower case, the first time, you need to inside the loop as well.

Answer (score 3):

An efficient way is to use a HashSet, this way the check is `O(1)`

```
static final Set<String> days = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(
       "monday", "tuesday", "wednesday", "thursday", "friday", "saturday", "sunday"));

public boolean isDay(String input) {
     return days.contains(input.toLowerCase());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an array of String, and loop through it check if your input matches any of them

```
public static boolean isDay(String input) {
    String days[] = { 
        "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday" 
        };
    for(String day : days) {
        if(input.equalsIgnoreCase(day))
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is dangling scan.nextLine(). Remove the line and it will work.

```
System.out.println("Great! Welcome back " + cust.getName() + ". What day of the week would you like "
        + "to book?(Sunday, November the 12th thru Saturday, November the 18th");

String day = scan.nextLine();
String dayLower = day.toLowerCase();
//scan.nextLine();


while (!"monday".equals(dayLower) && !dayLower.equals("tuesday") && !dayLower.equals("wednesday")
        && !dayLower.equals("thursday") && !dayLower.equals("friday") && !dayLower.equals("saturday")
        && !dayLower.equals("sunday")) {
    System.out.println("Error in entry. Please enter a day of the week.");
    day = scan.nextLine();
}
```

PS: Your approach is not the best approach though. @Peter Lawrey's solution is a better approach.